# sql queries embeded in php code don't get executed while working with cpanel

Tags: php, sql, connection, cpanel

I am new at cpanel and I encountered a problem. I have made a database and a database user for it in cpanel and successfully connected to them via my php code. In spite of that I have a successful connection to database but none of my queries run in the application code (while they run in the phpMyadmin!).

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $conn =new mysqli('localhost','myDBname','myDBpass','myDBuser');
    if($conn)
    echo "<script>alert('successful connection');</script>";
    $rawresults ="SELECT * FROM `articles`";
    $result = $conn->query($rawresults);
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
       echo "<script>alert('dd')</script>";
       $_SESSION["i"]=0;            
       while($results = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
              setcookie("searchResult","yes");
              $_SESSION["topic".$_SESSION["i"]]=$results['topic'];
              $_SESSION["name".$_SESSION["i"]]=$results['fileName'];
              $_SESSION["texts".$_SESSION["i"]]=$results['texts'];
              $_SESSION["i"]++;             
        }
        header('location:index.php');
    }

    else if($result->num_rows==0)
    { 
         echo "<script>alert('cc')</script>";
         setcookie("searchResult","yes");
         header('location:index.php');              
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is that I permanently face: alert(cc)!  While table 'articles'
contains lots of information and num_rows is a positive value.
I 'd like to mention again that connection to db has no problem and I get alert(successful connection).

Answer (score 0):

Try this after connecting:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error (' . $conn ->connect_errno . ') '
        . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ErichBSchulz  It say:     Connect Error (1129) Host 'server.bluednszone.com' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'.

Comment: You may be able to reset it via cpanel. I haven't seen that error but I suspect one of your connection strings is wrong